# Load scene in background while displaying animation

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I've seen a lot of questions like this, none of which work because they're in an old version of Swift (all the dispatch_global stuff).

My game currently freezes for several seconds before switching scenes. Any way to have an animation while the next scene loads?

Comment: Show your code in Game Scene and View Controller.

Comment: if you know the new way to dispatch....what is the problem?

Comment: Also, loading in a background thread requires a loading screen the way you are doing it.  Did you look for ways to create loading screens?